# File remove from selected files while multiple file upload in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there any process to remove file content while files are selected for upload using multiple file upload and update form after remove file to send data another php page with ajax call function. I am novice in file multiple file handling.

Comment: Wow that was a long sentence... The answer to your question is "yes probably", although it's hard to be sure with such a description...

Comment: Ideally you need a breakdown of what you want rather than a chunk of text or better yet some form of example where someone else has done it.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your requirement - you cant change anything in file ( image ) before uploading to server.PHP works on server not on client side OR Please explain your requirements.